# robocopy, make destination folders and files all lowercase

Tags: robocopy

I am using robocopy as part of a content pipeline (for app development). First i run it mirroring only the directory structure. Then i run it several times with /e (making use of /xf /xd etc).

For purposes of this question, imagine that my folder structure looks like:
C:\projects\projectname\Data\IrregularlyCasedFile.ext
C:\projects\projectname\Data\SubData\CamelCaseSucks.ext

And I am using robocopy to:

1. mirror all folder structure

   - below: `C:\projects\projectname\Data\`
   - to: `C:\projects\projectname\packages\data`
2. copy all .ext files, recursively
   eg, output would be:
   `C:\projects\projectname\packages\data\irregularlycasedfile.ext
   C:\projects\projectname\packages\data\subdata\camelcasesucks.ext`

Now I know how to do all of this with robocopy ~except~ the rename to lower case part, which is currently a totally separate step i had to resort to using a powershell script for.

Unfortunately this is quite slow compared to robocopy as it has to yet again iterate every single file in the output directory and do a rename operation.

***Can this be accomplished via robocopy alone?***

Comment: The behaviour will always be based on your script. There are quick and dirty ways to handle any data... then there is better ways to efficiently make it work, I think you should give an example of your code and once that's done for it to be push to be moved stack overflow?.

Comment: There are faster products than robocopy, such as FastCopy. I don't know of a way to change case during copy, but it's simple enough to do after the copy.